# javascript regex- replace all instances with one

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the words `XXX/XXX/XXX/`... with one `XXX/`

For example:

```
www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX
```

should be:

```
www.domain.com/XXX/section/XXX
```

How can i do it with regex instead of:

```
str.replace("XXX/XXX","XXX").replace("XXX/XXX","XXX").replace("XXX/XXX","XXX").replace("XXX/XXX","XXX").replace("XXX/XXX","XXX").replace("XXX/XXX","XXX");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

```js
const input = "www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX";

const expectedOutput = "www.domain.com/XXX/section/XXX"
const actualOutput = input.replace(/(\/XXX)\1+/g, "$1")

console.log("output", actualOutput)
```

## Explanation

the `()` will capture the match inside the parenthesis.

the `\1` and `$1` will use whats captured inside the first capture group, the `/XXX` in our case.

the `+` will ask for 1 or more repeats.

the `g` flag will cause the regex to be applied on the whole string, even if a match is found earlier.

the whole regex will look for an `/XXX` followed by another `/XXX` 1 or more times, then replacing whats matched with only one "/XXX".

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to match all occurrences of `/XXX` that are repeated 2 or more times in a row:

```js
var str = "www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX";

var strOut = str.replace(/(\/XXX){2,}/g, '$1');

console.log(strOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var str = "www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX";
str = str.replace(/(XXX\/*)+/g, "XXX/");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var url="www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX";
var regexer=/(XXX\/*)+/g;
url = url.replace(regexer, "XXX/");
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
function processUrl(url) {
  return url.replace(/www.domain.com(\/[^/]*)*\/section(\/[^/]*)*/g, "www.domain.com$1/section$2");
}
console.log(processUrl("www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX"));
console.log(processUrl("www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/YYY/YYY"));
console.log(processUrl("www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/ZZZ/ZZZ/ZZZ"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To capture and output only first occurrence of `XXX/*`:

```js
var url="www.domain.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/section/XXX/XXX";
var re=/(XXX\/*)+/g;
url = url.replace(re, "$1");
console.log(url)
```